# How to make a bot delete a message sent from itself

Tags: python, discord.py, nextcord

I have a Discord bot and I want it to delete a "Loading..." message. However it just deletes the user message for the command

```
@client.command()
async def run(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Loading...")
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send("Loading Complete!")
```

This raises insufficient permissions as it is trying to delete the user message instead of the message it just sent.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `delete_after` parameter which specifies after how much seconds the message will be deleted after sending.

```py
await ctx.send("Loading...", delete_after=3) #deleting after 3 seconds
```